# Is it possible to automate (non interactive) installation of RHEV (RedHat Enterprise Vertualization) without PXE

Tags: virtualization

I have need to automate (non interactive) installation of RHEV with out PXE. I have gone through the RHEV installation documentation. But did not find any way.

Please suggest if there is any way to achieve this.

-Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use PXE, I think your only option is

- prepare an image with all required RPMs already installed
- prepare an answer file

On the host you're provisioning for running RHEV:

- clone the image on the disk
- fix hostname as needed for avoiding duplicates
- run engine-setup --config-append=answerfile